# Connect to Postgres from Swift

Tags: database, swift, postgresql, database-connection

In a [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) app, how does one connect to a [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database server?

- In [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), we use [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) with an [compliant driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) to connect to a Postgres server, communicate SQL, and get a result set.
- In a [Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) app, we use [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) with a [compliant driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/) to do the same.

How to do the equivalent from Swift?

Comment: You can call any C code in Swift.

Comment: @Basil Bourque have u found any solution, if yes please share it with us

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use Postgres C API *libpq*. However, at least a thin layer of Swift will be needed to make it object-oriented and ARC compliant. An example implementation of that layer may be like so: [stepanhruda/PostgreSQL-Swift](https://github.com/stepanhruda/PostgreSQL-Swift).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [PostgresClientKit](https://github.com/codewinsdotcom/PostgresClientKit)